# Why is $\lim_{t\to\infty}e^{st}\to 0$ iff $\Re\{s\}<0$?

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, control-theory

For a complex variable $s=a+ib$ and the condition $\Re\{s\}<0$ we have the limit
$$\lim_{t\to\infty}e^{st}\to 0$$ 
*Question:* Why no condition for the imaginary part?

If $\Re\{s\}>0$ we have $a>0$, and if also $\Im\{s\}<0$ we have $b<0$, so why isn't
$$
\lim_{t\to \infty}e^{(a+ib)t}
=\lim_{t\to \infty}e^{at}e^{ibt}
\to"\infty\cdot 0"
\to 0\quad ?
$$

Comment: Look at the absolute value:  $|e^{st}|=|e^{at}||e^{ibt}|=e^{at}.$

Comment: I don't understand: for $a>0$ $e^{at}$ diverges, while the other term is limited but not null, so the whole limit diverges.

Comment: @N74 I updated with $"\infty\cdot 0"\to 0$.

Comment: First of all $\infty \cdot 0$ is an indeterminate form. Then $e^{ibt}$ does not tend to $0$ as in this case  $\Re\{s\}=0$ so the less than condition is not fulfilled.

Comment: $\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}e^{ibt}\neq 0$ for all $b\in R$. In fact the limit doesn't exist except for $b=0$. The complex number $e^{st}=e^{at}e^{ibt}$ lies on a circle with center the origin and radius $e^{at}$. The term $bt$ is the phase and determines at which point on the circle $e^{st}$ lies. So if $a>0$ the circle expands to infinity while if $a<0$ it shrinks down to the origin.

Answer (score 1):

Because 
$$|e^z|=|e^{a+ib}|=|e^a||e^{ib}|=|e^a|$$
therefore practically the real part of $z$ is useful and effective here. With your assumption $a>0$
$$|e^{(a+ib)t}|=|e^{at}|\to\infty$$
as $t\to\infty$.

Comment: … and for the same reason $|e^{zt}| \ge 1 \not\to 0$ for $\Re z \ge 0$.